# Eclipse with Subversive - regular svn diff view

Tags: eclipse, svn, diff

Previously I've used command line SVN without any wrappers.
Few days ago I switched to Eclipse with Subversive and have problems with diffs.
Team Sync perspective with Compare view is OK, but it displays whole file, not just changes.
Where I can find something similar to "svn diff" output? I need only changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Compare views show the entire file which makes sense, as its a GUI.  In the Compare view, there are buttons in the top right that enable you to skip from diff to diff (down and up), and the right-hand margin shows locations.  So, while its not exactly the same as the command-line, its just as functional.  Also, it gives you context for the changes, not just the changed line.

If you need to output a report, that's a little different.  You might be able to just click int the top pane, type Ctl-A to select all, Ctl-C to copy, and then paste into a text editor.  That might give you just the changes.

Comment: I knew that, but I thought I missed something because diff view is common. Anyway, I still can run it from terminal.